# Cannot create virtual environment in Pycharm 2019.1 with anaconda 3

Tags: anaconda, pycharm, virtualenv

How can I create a python virtual environment interpreter with Pycharm and Anaconda? The usual procedure doesn't work.

With new Pycharm 2019.1 and Anaconda 3, I am unable to create a virtual environment as required by Jupyter notebooks. Pycharm 2019.1 cannot find a version of pythonw.exe where it is expecting it to create a base interpreter.

Following the usual procedure in Pycharm to create a virtualenv interpreter (not a conda environnment python interpreter)

File->Settings->Project Interpreter->Add->Virtualenv page in pycharm

Leads to the  Window
Select New environment 
Location  --C:\Users\jackson\PycharmProjects\MyProject\Venv
Base Interpreter   Python 3.7 c:\users\jackson\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe

Leads to the following error

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\jackson\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\venv\scripts\nt\pythonw.exe'

The anaconda3\lib\venv\scripts\

Comment: Possibly related: [Error creating new Virtualenv environment in Pycharm 2019.1 using Anaconda3 2019.3 distribution](https://superuser.com/q/1422457/150988).

Comment: it is related but discussion was terminated so there was no resolution.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of a problem with particular versions of Anaconda. There is more info on the [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10822) which dates from around the same time as this question.

If that is the case, then running

```
conda update python
```

may update the installation and fix your issues.